# Parameter in find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following a guide to Ruby on Rails and there is something I don't understand. I have this model called `Comment` which `belongs_to` another two models, called `User` and `Book`.

This model's controller, `Comments` has the following `create` action:

```
def create
  book = Book.find(params[:comment][:book_id])
  comment = book.comments.build(comment_params)
  comment.user = current_user

  if comment.save
    redirect_to comment.book
  end
end
```

`comment_params` is just this:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
end
```

This `create` action is called when clicking the "Submit" button from this form, which is a partial called `_comments` located in the `books` view folder and rendered in the books' `show` action:

```
<%= form_for @book.comments.build do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: @book.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

`@book` is indeed defined in `books#show`.

I don't understand why I have to pass the `[:comment]` parameter to the `Book.find` method in order to find the book. I thought just the `[:book_id]` would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually passing the `:comment` parameter but rather accessing the `:book_id` that's nested in the `:comment` hash. Your `params` look something like:

```
{
  :comment => {
    :book_id => 1
  }
}
```

If you simply passed `params[:book_id]` you would get back `nil`.

Comment: Actually, I bet there IS `params[:book_id]` too (which comes from the route `/books/:book_id/comments`). Unless comment is a top-level resource, that is.

Answer (score 2):

If `book_id` is a field in `comments` table you don't need to retrieve the book. Just do

```
def create
  comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  comment.user = current_user

  if comment.save
    redirect_to comment.book
  end
end
```

Also, if the `User` model has a `comments` association, and in this action you are sure that a `current_user` is set, you can do

```
def create
  comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)

  if comment.save
    redirect_to comment.book
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean, "don't need the first line"? Where does `book` come from then?

Comment: `params[:comment][:book_id] `

Comment: Comment object contains the book id. that's all you need.

Comment: But you create that comment object through an unknown object `book`.